# ¿Cómo puedo asignar los id correctos al value de una opción?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un select que me carga los clientes que han realizado transacciones y me los muestra de esta forma con un select:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora..lo que he intentado es agregar el id de cada cliente como un  ya que actualmente esta solo

Aqui esta la parte que he logrado hacer, ya me sale el id, pero al parecer solo esta tomando el ultimo y solo ese lo agregar a value='', puedo hacer algo para que agregue los id respectivamente?

```
$("#color-" + id_color).append("<tr><td>" + data['fecha'] + "</td><td>" + data['cantidad'] + "</td><td><select id='clientes-" + id_color + "-" + data["fecha"] + "' class='form-control' Onchange='getUser(this)'></select></td></tr>");
        cantidad += parseInt(data['cantidad']);
         data["id_clientes"].forEach(function(id_cliente){
             id = "value='" + id_cliente + "'";
             //console.log(id); //Muestra los ids en consola
         });
         data["clientes"].forEach(function(cliente) {
             $("#clientes-" + id_color + "-" + data["fecha"]).append("<option " + id + ">" + cliente + "</option>");
         });
```

Aqui esta lo que me devuelve el server:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahi estan los nombres y los id de cada usuario.

Pero al agregarlos, me sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y deberia mostrar los id respectivos del servidor.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme con eso :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas hacer un solo bucle con un contador asi:

```
$("#color-" + id_color).append("<tr><td>" + data['fecha'] + "</td><td>" + data['cantidad'] + "</td><td><select id='clientes-" + id_color + "-" + data["fecha"] + "' class='form-control' Onchange='getUser(this)'></select></td></tr>");
        cantidad += parseInt(data['cantidad']);

         var i = 0;
         data["clientes"].forEach(function(cliente) {
             id = "value='" + data["id_clientes"][i] + "'";
             i++;
             $("#clientes-" + id_color + "-" + data["fecha"]).append("<option " + id + ">" + cliente + "</option>");
         });
```

Comment: Gracias ya funciona :D